# Can't convert string to UTF-8 with Alamofire

Tags: swift, utf-8, alamofire

I have an API that I want to use with the Alamofire library, but I need use UTF-8 to make my API url support spaces and Arabic. I have tried these two ways with no success.

```
let d = "ddd dd"
let f = String(d.utf8)!
let bb = String(UTF8String: f.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!
let encodedName = d.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of actual text? Could you explain what "no success" means?

Comment: @matt Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.ulo/sendmsg.php?msg=\(bb)", encoding: .JSON).validate().responseJSON { Response in

Comment: this my api I want to send value of `bb`

Comment: I got error like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095613/send-arabic-words-and-spaces-to-api-not-work-with-alamofire

Comment: So you are just repeating your earlier question?

Answer (score 0):

These lines are wrong:

```
let f = String(d.utf8)!
let bb = String(UTF8String: f.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!
```

You do not need or want a C string. And you do not need to convert to UTF8; a Swift string is already unicode. And every time you use an exclamation mark (`!`) you are saying "Please crash me" - so you cannot be surprised when you do in fact crash.

Comment: Why? if I does not unwrap it with ! I got error, what I should write?

Comment: You can unwrap whatever you like. But do not use `!`. If it is nil, you will crash.